# safe way to remain session in react universal web application ( react.js)

Tags: reactjs, api, express, authentication, session

I'm building universal web application using react.js.
I use express for server sider rendering, and there is another `server-side api server` which deliver json object from database.

so when my react client fetch api for signIn or signUp,
api server make jwt token and set cookie in response `Set-Cookie` header with httpOnly options which for prevent XSS security  problem occur.

after api server response, I could find cookie in `application` tab in google chrome inspector.

Here my problem begins. because of httpOnly option, client can't read document.cookie, so no ways to convince to check session is valid on every page refreshing.

how can I deal with this?

naive approach could be getting rid of httpOnly options from response, but might brings another issues of bad security.

Comment: With you having the cookie in client as httpOnly I believe now the is no need to have to use ```document.cookie```.  Isn't the whole point for server session handling for server to handle your session?

Comment: yeah api server handle cookie, which means api server has responsible make cookie and send it to client via http Header `Set-Cookie`, but client still need to check cookie exist or not in every page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your question you want your React App to check if the cookie exists, and from my knowledge unfortunately that can never be done as long as that cookie is an httpOnly cookie, cause if that was possible then it would defeat the purpose of having server session cookie flagged as httpOnly.

**Note the following about httpOnly cookies**

`An HttpOnly cookie is not accessible via non-HTTP methods, such as calls via JavaScript (e.g"document.cookie")`

**So now what is the solution to knowing if user has a session cookie**

- So routes that need user to be logged in you can make a middleware in your server whereby it first validates the cookie provided by the client and if that is a valid cookie you can then push them down to the called route.
- And lets say the user cookie expired then most definitely the cookie wont be the in cookie storage and when a request is sent no cookie will be sent and your middleware validation mentioned above will handle that just fine and then that's how you can manage everything

Comment: unless there are some point that I'm not clear, really appreciate your answer. thank you